# XML data to HTML form and back

Tags: php, html, xml, forms, automation

I am storing data in XML databases. Now I want users to be able to edit certain records. E.g. my db could look like this:

```
<items>
  <item id="1">
    <prop_a>some text</prop_a>
    <prop_b>TRUE</prop_b>
    <prop_c>29.01.2010</prop_c>
    ...
  </item>
  // next item and so on
```

Is there a tool which can generate a html form (for which it will certainly need additional information, e.g. which fields are text fields, which might be checkboxes, or drop-down fields, whatever), fill it with the data for one record (this would be everything in `<item>`), and also take the user input (GET / POST content) and convert this again into XML? Maybe it could even do some checks, maybe via a call-back function. (I'd prefer something free in PHP to make the wish-list complete :)

Comment: Indeed one direction (XML -> HTML) is easy using XSLT.

Unfortunately, so far nobody has come up with a solution for the other direction, i.e. evaluating the user data and generating XML from this (in a flexible and configurable way).

Answer (score 3):

You could to use a [XSLT](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xslt.php) document to transform that XML into HTML.

Comment: But that's only one direction. I'd still need something to evaluate the form data...